# Intersection of a 3D Grid's Vertices

Tags: algorithm, grid, computational-geometry, linear-algebra, intersection

Imagine an enormous 3D grid (procedurally defined, and potentially infinite; at the very least, 10^6 coordinates per side).  At each grid coordinate, there's a primitive (e.g., a sphere, a box, or some other simple, easily mathematically defined function).

I need an algorithm to intersect a ray, with origin outside the grid and direction entering it, against the grid's elements.  I.e., the ray might travel halfway through this huge grid, and then hit a primitive.  Because of the scope of the grid, an iterative method [EDIT: (such as ray marching) ]is unacceptably slow.  What I need is some closed-form [EDIT: *constant time* ]solution for finding the primitive hit.

One possible approach I've thought of is to determine the amount the ray *would* converge each time step toward the primitives on each of the eight coordinates surrounding a grid cell in some modular arithmetic space in each of x, y, and z, then divide by the ray's direction and take the smallest distance.  I have no evidence other than intuition to think this might work, and Google is unhelpful; "intersecting a grid" means intersecting the grid's *faces*.

Notes:

- I really only care about the surface normal of the primitive (I could easily find that given a distance to intersection, but I don't care about the distance per se).
- The type of primitive intersected isn't important at this point.  Ideally, it would be a box.  Second choice, sphere.  However, I'm assuming that whatever algorithm is used might be generalizable to other primitives, and if worst comes to worst, it doesn't really matter for this application anyway.

Comment: Are you by any chance working on a ray tracer?

Comment: Of a sort--I'm trying to make a visualizer for extremely large numbers.  I'm trying to write a fragment shader that essentially raytraces that grid.

Comment: How large are the objects at the vertices, relative to the size of the faces?

Answer (score 2):

Here's another idea:
The ray can only hit a primitive when all of the x, y and z coordinates are close to integer values.
If we consider the parametric equation for the ray, where a point on the line is given by

```
p=p0 + t * v
```

where p0 is the starting point and v is the ray's direction vector, we can plot the distance from the ray to an integer value on each axis as a function of t. e.g.:

```
dx = abs( ( p0.x + t * v.x + 0.5 ) % 1 - 0.5 )
```

This will yield three sawtooth plots whose periods depend on the components of the direction vector (e.g. if the direction vector is (1, 0, 0), the x-plot will vary linearly between 0 and 0.5, with a period of 1, while the other plots will remain constant at whatever p0 is.

You need to find the first value of t for which all three plots are below some threshold level, determined by the size of your primitives. You can thus vastly reduce the number of t values to be checked by considering the plot with the longest (non-infinite) period first, before checking the higher-frequency plots.

I can't shake the feeling that it may be possible to compute the correct value of t based on the periods of the three plots, but I can't come up with anything that isn't scuppered by the starting position not being the origin, and the threshold value not being zero. :-/

Comment: I like the way this line of reasoning is going.  I think the idea of using the wave periods to calculate the intersection is a great one.  I think you meant triangle wave instead of saw wave though.  To intersect a sphere, what is needed is the first t such that the length of the vec3 formed by sampling each of the triangle waves at the same t is less than the threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you'll need to do is to express the line in the form of a function. From there, you will just mathematically have to calculate if the ray intersects with each object, as and then if it does make sure you get the one it collides with closest to the source.

This isn't fast, so you will have to do a lot of optimization here. The most obvious thing is to use bounding boxes instead of the actual shapes. From there, you can do things like use Octrees or BSTs (Binary Space Partitioning).

Well, anyway, there might be something I am overlooking that becomes possible through the extra limitations you have to your system, but that is how I had to make a ray tracer for a course.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but, as I wrote, an iterative algorithm wouldn't be much help.

Although in general acceleration data structures are good for ray tracing, no matter how you group objects into a BVH, I can always come up with a way of looking at the grid that will make it too slow.

Acceleration data structures are favorable because they allow the ray to quickly jump through empty space.  Unfortunately, in a dense grid, there's not much of that.

Comment: Because it steps a ray through the grid.  For an infinitely large grid, that could take an infinitely long amount of time.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. It uses mathematics. Yes, for an infinite number of objects, you will still need infinite collision checks. I don't know a way around that, but I also doubt there is any at all.

Answer (score 0):

You state in the question that an iterative solution is unacceptably slow - I assume you mean iterative in the sense of testing every object in the grid against the line.

Iterate instead over the grid cubes that the line intersects, and for each cube test the 8 objects that the cube intersects. Look to [Bresenham's line drawing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) for how to find which cubes the line intersects.
Note that Bresenham's will not return *absolutely every* cube that the ray intersects, but for finding which primitives to test I'm fairly sure that it'll be good enough.
It also has the nice properties:

1. Extremely simple - this will be handy if you're running it on the GPU
2. Returns results iteratively along the ray, so you can stop as soon as you find a hit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  By iterative, I meant stepping along the ray's path.  Bresenham's could be adapted (noting that cells' elements intrude into the its neighbors' cells).  but unfortunately, it's still iterative.  It's a problem because, for example, if I'm looking down a row of the grid, so I can see other the other side, then the number of tests is linear in the grid's dimension, because I never hit anything.  For grid dimensions like 10^6 or 10^9, you see that it quickly becomes unfeasible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

1. Determine the function of the ray;
2. Say the grid is divided in different planes in z axis, the ray will intersect with each 'z plane' (the plane where the grid nodes at the same height lie in), and you can easily compute the coordinate (x, y, z) of the intersect points from the ray function;
3. Swipe z planes, you can easily determine which intersect points lie in a cubic or a sphere;
4. But the ray may intersects with the cubics/spheres between the z planes, so you need to repeat the 1-3 steps in x, y axises. This will ensure no intersection is left off.
5. Throw out the repeated cubics/spheres found from x,y,z directions searches.